# Books that gives geometric interpretation of topology.

Tags: general-topology

I know basic topology like connectedness, compactness, product and quotient spaces, uryshon lemma etc. I have been looking for a book that gives more geometric interpretation of the subject. Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might be interested in the book [Introduction to Topological Manifolds](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1441979395) by John Lee.  The preface states that a more accurate title for this book might have been "Introduction to Topology with an Emphasis on Manifolds."

Comment: Will I be able to go through it?

Comment: @user398623 It doesn't assume prior knowledge of topology, and it can be used as an introduction to topology something like Munkres.  So I think it's accessible to you.  You can read the preface at the Amazon page I linked to, which might give you more of an idea if you have the prerequisites.

Answer (score 3):

You can read "A First Course in Geometric Topology and Differential Geometry" by Ethan D. Bloch. Also, "An Introduction to Geometric Topology" by Bruno Martelli makes a good read. By the way, a quick Google Search yields several results. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

Since you know that basis and want a beginner level book on topology from a more geometric perspective, I would suggest Sue Goodman's book Beginning Topology and Kinsey's Topology of Surfaces.